# C++ cannot convert QLineEdit to char

Tags: c++, qt

У меня такой код, по моей логике, он должен присваивать то, что вводиться в `QLineEdit - serialNumberText`, переменной `serialnumberPDF`.

Но я получаю ошибку:

> "C++ cannot convert QLineEdit to char"

Код:

```
QLineEdit *serialNumberText;
char serialnumberPDF[3];

void Main::finish(){
  strcpy(serialNumberText, serialnumberPDF);
  // ОСТАЛЬНОЙ КОД //
}
```

Как он работает, у меня есть `QLineEdit`, куда я вводу к примеру 4005, далее, нажимаю на кнопку "`Finish`", теперь, программка должна из `serialNumberText`, сохранить число в переменную `serialnumberPDF`, и далее, сохранить это в PDF файл - `.arg(serialnumberPDF)`

Добавляю код по просьбе:

```
char serialnumberPDF[3];

void Main::finish(){
    if (sdRemoveCheck->isChecked()){
        QByteArray text = serialNumberText->text().toLocal8Bit();
        text.resize(sizeof(serialnumberPDF) -1);
        strcpy(serialnumberPDF, text.data());
        pdf_creation2();
        close();
    }else{
        QMessageBox messageBox;
        messageBox.critical(0, "Error", "Remove first mircoSD Card");
        messageBox.setFixedSize(500, 200);
    }

QString SerialNumber = QString("<tr class=\"method\">"
                                   "<th style=\"background: #e3e4e4;\">S/N</th>"
                                   "<td>%1</td>"
                                   "<td></td>"
                               "</tr>").arg(serialnumberPDF);
```

Comment: Расскажите лучше, что Вы собираетесь потом делать с `serialNumberText`.

Comment: И с `serialNumberPDF` тоже.

Comment: обновил вопрос, проверьте

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы хотите заполнить массив тем, что содержится в `QLineEdit`, сделайте так:

```
#include<QByteArray>
#include<QString>

QLineEdit *serialNumberText;
char serialnumberPDF[3];

void Main::finish(){
    QByteArray text = serialNumberText->text().toLocal8Bit();
    text.resize(sizeof(serialnumberPDF) - 1);
    strcpy(serialnumberPDF, text.data());
}
```

**PS**: Массив char? Серьезно? Вы ведь не на C пишете. Используйте `QString`, ну или если у вас там что-то принимает именно массив char, то используйте `QByteArray`. И не нужны будут эти приседания с `strcpy`

Comment: к сожалению я пока привык к int и char... нужно будет как-нибудь переучится.

Comment: @Insider, Начинайте прямо сейчас. Огромная куча ошибок в коде приходится на   всякие `memcpy`, `memset`, `strcpy` и т.п. И это у опытных разработчиков в больших проектах

Comment: к сожалению так же, критическое закрытие

Comment: @Insider, проблема в другой части кода. Запускайтесь под отладчиком и смотрите где падает

Comment: падает именно в этой части кода, показывает сам отладчик. остальное все проверил.

Comment: @Insider, на какой строке?

Comment: QByteArray text = serialNumberText->text().toLocal8Bit();

Comment: @Insider, `serialNumberText` чему равен? Уж не ноль-ли?

Comment: ну как бы, сначала он просто есть, потом я ввожу туда к примеру 123.. и нажимаю на кнопку.. после этого программа критически закрывается.. а отладчик показывает на эту строку. могу передать вам весь код программы.. может быть так бы поймете быстрее

Comment: @Insider, если честно мне не хочется заниматься отладкой за вас. Ошибка скорее всего в том что serialNumberText указывает куда-то не туда. Может значение указателя неверное, может объект уже уничтожен, когда вызывается метод `finish`.

Comment: сейчас я переместил это в отдельную функцию... и объекты точно не могут быть уничтожены. что вы имеете ввиду под "указывает не туда"?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46283/discussion-between-insider-and-yrhetatejlb).

Answer (score 1):

Всё правильно вам компилятор пишет. Он безуспешно попытался преобразовать указатель на `QLineEdit` в указатель на `char`.

Предположим, что от пользователя требуется ввести в поле некоторое число:

```
// где-то ранее описаны QLineEdit* m_lineEdit и QPushButton* m_button
// затем вызван connect(m_button, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(slotOnClick()));

void slotOnClick()
{
    QString str = m_lineEdit->text();
    if (str.isEmpty()) {
        // скажите пользователю, что он ничего не ввёл
        return;
    }
    bool ok = false;
    int serialNumber = str.toInt(&ok);
    if (!ok) {
        // скажите пользователю, что он должен был ввести число, а не абракадабру
        return;
    }
    // требуемый вам serialNumber готов к использованию,
    // теперь можно делать так:
    QString result = QString("Вы ввели число: %1").arg(serialNumber);
    qDebug() << result;
}
```

Comment: к сожалению получаю теперь такую ошибку class QString has no member named toAscii

Comment: Используйте `QByteArray QString::toLatin1() const`.

Comment: serialnumberPDF  is not a class or namespace... я немного обновил вопрос, может теперь поможет?

Comment: в конце концов, после нажатия на кнопку, программа закрывается.. кнопка работает правильно

Comment: Скорее всего ваша программа не закрывается, а аварийно завершается. Не сомневаюсь, что кнопка работает правильно - не правильно работает ваш слот. Вероятнее всего вы где-то неправильно работаете с памятью.

Comment: Поясните подробнее, какую проблему вы хотите решить, приведите [минимальный пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). А то всё это пока больше похоже на ["ошибку молотка"](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy).

Comment: да, критическое закрытие, сейчас приведу больше кода в пример.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46125/discussion-between-insider-and-aleks-andr).